# Get a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction from a System.Transactions.TransactionScope

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

Is there a way to get a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction` from an instance of a `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` or a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`?

Let say I'm `using` a `TransactionScope` but want to pass a `SqlTransaction` to some legacy code. Is it possible to get a `Transaction` from a `TransactionScope` or a `SqlConnection`?

```vb
Using scope As TransactionScope = GetTransactionScope()
    Using conn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = GetConnection(Globals.ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()  'this will automatically enlist itself in a transaction if there is an ambient one created by `TransactionScope`

        LegacyFunction(transaction) '<-- how can I get the `transaction` here??

        ExecuteSQL(conn, sql, params)

        conn.Close()
    End Using

    scope.Complete()
End Using
```

Comment: Why you want to pass it in Legacyfunction ?? Because your code was already runnig under TransactionScope block.

Comment: It's an old function that accepts a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction` as an argument. I can't change that function, but I want to use `TransactionScope`. I think I can use `System.Transactions.Current`, but that does not return a  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction`.

Comment: Presumably your ExecuteSQL does something involving a SQLCommand? Have you looked at whether the [SqlCommand.Transaction Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.transaction(v=vs.110).aspx) is getting set when it enlists?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the ctor that takes a Transaction

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction;

    // Start a local transaction.
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

    // Must assign both transaction object and connection 
    // to Command object for a pending local transaction
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;

    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope ts = New TransactionScope(transaction))
        {
            LegacyFunction(transaction);
            ....
        }
        transaction.Commit();
        Console.WriteLine("Commit");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

        // Attempt to roll back the transaction. 
        try
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred 
            // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as 
            // a closed connection.
            Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TransactionScope takes a Transaction as parameter, not a SqlTransaction

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by Blam one more thing is that - `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` is totally different concept than `IDBTransaction`. So you can see in the Blam's answer - When calling **BeginTransaction** on the **DbConnection** object, you can pass that transaction object in a different method.

In short you can't use `TransactionScope` in your legacy function.